# Solving for $x$: $3^x + 3^{x+2} = 5^{2x-1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

$3^x + 3^{x+2} = 5^{2x-1}$

Pretty lost on this one. I tried to take the natural log of both sides but did not get the result that I desire.

I have the answer but I would like to be pointed in the right direction. Appreciated if you can give me some hints to this question, thanks!

Comment: By 5^2x do you mean $5^2x$ or $5^{2x}$?  I suspect the latter, but an edit has chosen the former.  Parentheses, please.

Comment: @rossmillikan yes it would 5^(2x-1), same thing for 3^(x+2)

Comment: @RossMillikan Most definitively. Note the spacing when he wrote 3^x+2 and 5^2x.

Comment: Hint: factor out $3^x$.

Comment: Factor $3^x$in the left hand side, then hit both sides with logs use log rules, then solve for $x$.

Comment: $3^x\cdot(1 + 3^2) = 5^{2x-1}$ take logs of both side, combine terms of x (like @EricAuld said) and you should find x pretty easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $$3^x+3^{x+2}=5^{2x-1}\\10\cdot 3^x=5^{2x-1}\\50\cdot 3^x=25^x$$  Now you can take logs

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

$$3^x + 3^{x + 2} = 3^x + 3^x 3^2 = 3^x + 9 \cdot 3^x = 10 \cdot 3^x$$

So your equation is now

$$10 \cdot 3^x = 5^{2x - 1}$$

Try taking logarithms and simplifying.

Answer (score 2):

$$  10 \cdot 3^x = 5^{2x-1}  $$
$$  50 \cdot 3^x = 5^{2x} = 25^x $$
$$  50 \cdot 3^x = 25^x $$

Comment: Sire, my I found you in the Honorable Chat?

Answer (score 0):

Just take $$3^x$$ as common factor on right side then
$$3^x(1+3^2)=5^{2x-1}\Rightarrow  ln({3^x(1+3^2)}) = ln(5^{2x-1})\Rightarrow xln(3) + ln(10) = (2x-1)ln(5)\Rightarrow ln(10)+ln(5)=2xln(5)-xln(3)\Rightarrow x=\frac{ln(10)+ln(5)}{2ln(5)-ln(3)}$$